# IE Mobile Emulator with chrome or firefox

Tags: testing, mobile, windows-mobile, ie-mobile

So chrome and firefox allow you to change your user agent to different Android and IOS handsets.

Is there an option available for IE mobile?

Is  there any IE mobile inspector tool available?

Answer (score 0):

You could install a plugin that enables you to specify a user agent string and enter your own manually.

The UA string for the Xda I have sat on my desk is:

`Xda_Mantle/240x320 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows CE; IEMobile 7.6)`

To inspect the HTML you could perhaps use [Firebug lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) and access your site through a [Windows Mobile emulator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=9263).